# Location of resources and namespacing in packages

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

My package needs controllers, models and views.

I'm confused as to where these should be placed and how they should be namespaced.

For example, controllers. Do they go in:

```
/workbench/my-corp/my-app/src/controllers
```

Or should they go in:

```
/workbench/my-corp/my-app/src/my-corp/my-app/Controllers
```

And should they be namespaced? If so, to what?

Comment: Are you using PSR-0 or PSR-4 autoloading?

Answer (score 0):

Laravels workbench works in the same way as the vendor directory, with PSR-0 autoloading you would place your controllers within:

```
/workbench/Company/Package/src/Company/Package/Controllers
```

And they should be namespaced as `namespace Company\Package\Controllers`.

Your `composer.json` within the `/workbench/Company/Package/` directory would then have a psr-o section added to the autoload section like so:

```
...

"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Company\\Package": "src/"
    }
},

...
```

Then running `php artisan dump-autoload` from the command line will get artisan to run a composer dump autoload for the workbench packages.